# Office Add-in : Doesn't load in mobile

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

I have an office add-in for which I enabled **MobileFormFactor** under **VersionOverridesV1_1**. It used to work fine in my android mobile earlier. But, all of the sudden it shows blank page. Working fine in outlook web.

Any advise on this?

Comment: Here is my manifest https://vaddins.vtiger.com/office/manifest.xml

Comment: Did you change some configuration? I view your manifest, it has no issue. You could try to test your add-in, Please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins

Comment: I did not change any configuration. I have no idea what is the problem here, but reinstalling the add-in fixed the issue. I appreciate your help @AlinaLi